# Random variables of a random sample are not equal

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

In statistics we describe a sample as $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d random variables, where $X_i\colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. It is clear to me that identically distributed does not mean that the random variables are equal. However, I don't see why they should not be equal when drawn as random sample.

Suppose, I conduct the same fair coin flip experiment twice, meaning $X_1\sim\mathrm{Ber}(p), X_2\sim\mathrm{Ber}(p)$. In terms of probability $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be identical mappings, correct? We do the same thing (tossing a coin) but twice, so the cannot differ. I don't understand in what terms they differ from each other and why they generate different $\sigma$-algebras.

My particular problem is the fallacy that, if I would assume them to be equal, we have that $\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(X_1)$ which leads to nonsensical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "In terms of probability $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be identical mappings, correct?"

No.

If you model the tossing of $2$ coin flips using the same coin then we usually go for outcome space $\Omega=\{T,H\}^2$.

This with $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(\Omega)$ and a suitable probability measure $P$ that is determined by its values on singletons $\{\omega\}$.

Since we are dealing with the *same* coin we meet the condition: $$P(\{(H,H),(H,T)\})=P(\{(H,H),(T,H)\})$$
in words: the probability on heads for the first flip is the same as the probability on heads for the second flip.

Then we have the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ prescribed by $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto\omega_1$ and $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto\omega_2$ respectively.

These functions do not have $\mathbb R$ as codomain (as is mostly requested for a random variable) but that is just a technical problem that can be solved by e.g. identifying $H$ with $1$ and $T$ with $0$.

Then $X_1,X_2$ are iid, but we do not have $X_1=X_2$.

---

Final remark: if we are dealing with two coins that are both flipped once and the probability on heads is the same for the coins then we use this model as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the events of getting heads in two independent tosses of a fair coin. Then $A$ and $B$ are independent and $P(A)=P(B)$ but $A \neq B$ right? Same thing happens with random variables. In  fact if $X=I_A$ and $Y=I_B$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent with same distribution but they are not equal.

Comment: If we have the same underlying process behind the coin toss, why should $A\ne B$? Could you give a detailed example of what you mean? I don't know if it is notation, but I don't understand it.

Comment: $\Omega =\{HH,TT,HT,TH\}$. $A=\{HH,HT\}$ and $B=\{HH,TH\}$. So $A \neq B$. @EpsilonDelta

Comment: But this is not the model of a random sample. This would be the description of conidering two consecutive coin tosses as a single realization of a consecutive coin toss.